# How to display last names and numbers of all managers together with the number of employees that are his/her subordinates

Tags: sql, oracle11g

This is the schema [image]
\,
I  try using  inners  but the results were trash

```
SELECT
     employees.last_name   AS last_name,
     COUNT(employees.job_id) AS EMPLOYEES_Subordinates,
     COUNT(employees.manager_id) AS Manager_Numbers
 FROM
     employees left
     JOIN departments ON departments.manager_id = employees.manager_id
 GROUP BY
     employees.last_name
 ORDER BY
 EMPLOYEES_Subordinates desc;
```

---

( i really don't know how to show you the tables from hr)
If any 1 has the HR in Oracle Database and have time to help me , I gladly appreciate .

Answer (score 0):

not quite sure but try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    e.LAST_NAME
    ,(SELECT COUNT(ee.EMPLOYEE_ID) FROM EMPLOYEES ee WHERE ee.MANAGER_ID = e.EMPLOYEE_ID) AS 'NUMBER OF WORKERS'
FROM EMPLOYEES e
WHERE MANAGER_ID IS NULL
```